# Отображение сторонних артефактов над картой

Tags: android, google-maps-api

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
В процессе отрисовки Google Map, над ней выводится произвольная иконка из папки drawable.
Более того, не редко эта иконка так и остается на экране.
При этом сама карта отрисовывется правильно, маркеры проставляются, выводимая иконка вообще ни где не задействована... 
Может кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой?

Comment: скриншот и имя иконки в студию!

Comment: Как ни странно, но при сборке приложения на другой машине глюк не повторился. Завтра проверю на основной и выложу скрины. Сейчас же могу сказать, что имя иконки значения не имеет, так как при удалении выводимой... просто выводится другая. Ни одна из этих иконок на данный момент не используется ни в разметке, ни в коде приложения (до них еще просто не дошел)

Answer (score 0):

После перезагрузки тестового девайса артефакты при отображении карты проявляться перестали. Ни с рабочей. ни с домашней машины указанную ошибку повторить не удалось.
Вероятно проблема был в самом девайсе.